# How i can check a Row of DatagridView is Checked or Not

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

i have a column type Checkbox.
How i can check a Row of DatagridView is Checked or UnChecked

Comment: possible duplicate of [loop through datagridview column and check checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675269/loop-through-datagridview-column-and-check-checkbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any code which you have done already?

Also take a look at this question:  [loop through datagridview column and check checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675269/loop-through-datagridview-column-and-check-checkbox)   it is doing something similar so should be helpfull.

Comment: If you're answer is basically just a link to another question then that's an indication that this is a duplicate. Please either just leave a comment and/or flag the question as duplicate.

Comment: Its not an exact duplicate, just that the solution provided in the link with a little alteration would probably solve his issue

Comment: OK. i need convert Object to Boolean. Thanks