# Looping Through DataGridView display Headers

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have been looking at other post and have figured out when using the code from this post [loop through datagridview column and check checkbox][1]

[1]: [loop through datagridview column and check checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675269/loop-through-datagridview-column-and-check-checkbox) and other ones or the code that I came up with

```
string cName;
int i;

foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in Results.Columns)
{
    cName = c.DisplayIndex.ToString();
    i = Int32.Parse(cName);

    MessageBox.Show(c.HeaderText);
}
```

this doesn't loop through the display. So what I have done is turn `AllowUserToReorderColumns` on and when they move a column I would like to loop through the display columns and show a message box with the names of the display columns in the new order.

As you can tell that I have found the `displayIndex` proptery but I cannot figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code just loops through the Columns in the order which it was added. It will not be the same order the column is being displayed.

You need to sort the columns in the display order. You can do it using the `OrderBy` method of Linq with the `DisplayIndex` property. You can also optionally filter the hidden columns.

```
var columnsInDisplayOrder = Results.Columns
    .Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
    .Where(x => x.Visible)
    .OrderBy(x => x.DisplayIndex);

foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in columnsInDisplayOrder)
{
    MessageBox.Show(c.HeaderText);
}
```

Comment: You might want to add .Where(x => x.Visible) as well since this code will show hidden columns

Comment: can you explain this to me. I don't understand why this is working?

Comment: @user3120232 I've edited my answer to add little bit information. If still you can't understand, please ask specific question about which part of the code you don't understand.